# Appending new data to an existing JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, json, microsoft-metro

I have searched high and low, and far and wide for a solution to this, and have spent the last few weeks trying to implement my own solution, but I just can't come up with anything.

I would greatly appreciate any help at all!

I have a file, which looks like, (file.json):

```
{
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "OneTel Mobile Bill",
    "Amount": "39.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  }
}
```

And in my app, when I create a new 'Expense', I want to append that new Expense to this existing JSON file, so it looks like so:

```
{
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "OneTel Mobile Bill",
    "Amount": "39.90",
    "Due": "28/12/2011",
    "Recurrence": "1 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "01/01/2002"
  },
  "Expense": {
    "Name": "Loan Repayment",
    "Amount": "50.00",
    "Due": "08/03/2012",
    "Recurrence": "3 Months",
    "Paid": "0",
    "LastPaid": "08/12/2011"
  }
}
```

And this is how I am creating the JSON and writing to the file:

```
async public void WriteToFile(string type, string data)
{
    file = await folder.GetFileAsync(file.FileName);
    IRandomAccessStream writestream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);


    IOutputStream outputstream = writestream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
    DataWriter datawriter = new DataWriter(outputstream);
    datawriter.WriteString(data);

    await datawriter.StoreAsync();
    outputstream.FlushAsync().Start();
}

private void CreateExpenseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Create the Json file and save it with WriteToFile();
    JObject jobject =
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("Expense",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("Name", NameTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Amount", AmountTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Due", DueTextBox.Text),
                    new JProperty("Recurrence", EveryTextBox.Text + " " + EveryComboBox.SelectionBoxItem),
                    new JProperty("Paid", "0"),
                    new JProperty("LastPaid", "Never")
                           )
                         )
                   );
    try
    {
        WriteToFile(Expenses, jobject.ToString());

        // Close the flyout now.
        this.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.Write(exception.Message);

    }
}
```

I am using the Json.NET library from James Newton King, and it's pretty awesome but even after reading the included documentation, I have absolutely no idea how to read the JSON file and append data to it.

Are there any samples around that demonstrate how this is done, or can you recommend another library for C# that would allow me to accomplish this?

## Edit

This is how I am reading a single expense from the json file:

```
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);
        Expense expense = new Expense
        {
            Amount = (string)json["Expense"]["Amount"],
            Due = (string)json["Expense"]["Due"],
            Name = (string)json["Expense"]["Name"]
        };

        Debug.Write(expense.Amount);
```

Comment: Do you ever read from the file? Do you ever deserialize the data into objects?

Comment: I have updated my question and included how I read from the file. But, that's another problem; I know how to read 1 'Expense', but now how to read values from multiples Expenses in the one file. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can read directly into an `Expense` object, you should be able to add such an object to a `List<Expense>` - add the new data as an `Expense` object to the list (directly from your form data, or otherwise).

At this point you should be able to write out the `List<Expense>` out using JSON.NET - it should take care of creating the list.

I suggest you always save a `List<Expense>`, even if it contains only one item as it would make serializing and deserializing easier.

Comment: Thank you @Oded. So, if I understand you correctly, I can read from the file, convert it into List<Expense>, append new data, then save it all to the file again; overwriting the existing content of that file with everything?

Comment: @Jason - JSON.NET should be able to directly convert to a `List<Expense>`, and you have understood perfectly. The only problem with this approach is that the larger the file gets the worse the performance will be.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Oded! For the time being, this is just a personal project and aren't too fussed by lack of performance, but as the app evolves I'll surely look into a more suitable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to deserialize the data in to a object Expence and add your data, then serialize the object (list of objects) to file.

Comment: Thanks @Fossmo, I'll come back later to upvote once I have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @Jason You never came back it seams :P